# Multiple counts in a single SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these three distinct queries :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [myDb].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE Bathtub is  null

SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [myDb].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE Bathroom is  null

SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [myDb].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE Toilet is  null
```

I want to see their counts in a single query. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Sub Queries! Learn some basics of SQL https://blog.sqlauthority.com/

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [myDb].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE Bathtub is  null) AS BathTub,

(SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [myDb].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE Bathroom is  null) AS Bathroom,

(SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [myDb].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE Toilet is  null) AS Toilet
```

*Warning* Overheads involved in case if you are worried about performance

Answer (score 1):

Try this (this is oracle, I suppose is not different in mysql):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Bathtub IS NULL THEN 1 END) Bathtub, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Bathroom IS NULL THEN 1 END) Bathroom,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Toilet IS NULL THEN 1 END) Toilet 
from [myDb].[dbo].[Properties];
```

Answer (score 1):

Or write it like this:

```
SELECT total-BT cnt_bt, total-BR cnt_br, total-TL cnt_tl FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) total, COUNT(Bathtub) BT, COUNT(Bathroom) BR, COUNT(Toilet) TL
  FROM [myDb].[dbo].[Properties]
) subq
```

Answer (score 1):

Try union with customized description

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 'Bathtub is null counts' desc
  FROM [myDb].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE Bathtub is  null
union
SELECT COUNT(*),'Bathroom is null counts' desc
  FROM [myDb].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE Bathroom is  null
union
SELECT COUNT(*), 'Toilet is null counts' desc
  FROM [myDb].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE Toilet is  null
```

or

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN Bathtub IS NULL THEN 1 ElSE 0 END) as Bathtub_count, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Bathroom IS NULL THEN 1 ElSE 0 END) as Bathroom_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN Toilet IS NULL THEN 1 ElSE 0 END) as Toilet_count
from [myDb].[dbo].[Properties]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this SQL `SUM()` function. Like below:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(Bathtub IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS Bathtub_count,
    SUM(IF(Bathroom IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS Bathroom_count,
    SUM(IF(Toilet IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS Toilet_count
FROM
    [ myDb ].[ dbo ].[ Properties ]
```